# Invalid column name of temp table

Tags: t-sql

I want to create a procedure in which I insert data into several tables. I need to get the inserted ID's so I create temp table in which I catch them. The problem is that I receive an error "Invalid column name 'app_guid'" and "Invalid column name 'app_nazwa_pliku'" but I create temp tables with such columns. Do you happen to know what's wrong with my code?

```
create procedure p_paseczek_przenies
as

declare @new_nr_sprawy varchar(50)

if object_id('tempdb..##paseczki') is not null drop table ##paseczki

select 
top 1 with ties
s.sp_numer as SprawaGlowna_sp_numer,
s.sp_id as SprawaGlowna_sp_id
,Paseczek.max_ak_id as Paseczek_max_ak_id
,apisp_data_przyjscia
,app_guid
,app_nazwa_pliku

into ##paseczki

from sprawa as s
join akcja as a on a.ak_sp_id=s.sp_id and ak_akt_id=111
join sprawa_powiazania as sp on s.sp_id=sp.sp_id and rodzaj_powiazania='SPRAWY POLUBOWNE'
join (select max(ak_id) max_ak_id,ak_sp_id from akcja 
where ak_akt_id=1089 
group by ak_sp_id) as Paseczek on Paseczek.ak_sp_id=sp.sp_id_powiazana
join akcja_pismo on apis_ak_id=max_ak_id
join akcja_pismo_przychodzace on apis_apisp_id=apisp_id
join akcja_pismo_plik on app_apis_id=apis_id
where s.sp_numer=@new_nr_sprawy
order by ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by s.sp_id order by paseczek.max_ak_id desc)

if exists (select * from ##paseczki) 

begin

    if object_id('tempdb..##akcja') is not null drop table ##akcja

    create table ##akcja (
    ak_id int
    ,apisp_data_przyjscia datetime
    ,app_guid varchar(max)
    ,app_nazwa_pliku varchar(max)
    )

    merge akcja as target using (
    select * from ##paseczki) as source on 1=0
    when not matched then insert
    (ak_akt_id, ak_sp_id, ak_kolejnosc, ak_interwal, ak_zakonczono, ak_pr_id, ak_publiczna) 
    values (1089,SprawaGlowna_sp_id,1,1,getdate(),5,1)
    output inserted.ak_id,source.apisp_data_przyjscia,source.app_guid,source.app_nazwa_pliku
    into ##akcja;

    insert into rezultat
    (re_ak_id, re_ret_id, re_data_planowana, re_us_id_planujacy, re_data_wykonania, re_us_id_wykonujacy, re_konczy)
    select ak_id,309,getdate(),5,getdate(),5,1 from ##akcja

    if object_id('tempdb..##akcja_pismo_przychodzace') is not null drop table ##akcja_pismo_przychodzace

    create table ##akcja_pismo_przychodzace (
    apisp_id int
    ,ak_id int
    ,app_guid varchar(max)
    ,app_nazwa_pliku varchar(max)
    )

    merge akcja_pismo_przychodzace as target using (
    select * from ##akcja) as source on 1=0
    when not matched then insert
    (apisp_data_przyjscia)
    values (apisp_data_przyjscia)
    output inserted.apisp_id,source.ak_id,source.app_guid,source.app_nazwa_pliku
    into ##akcja_pismo_przychodzace;

    if object_id('tempdb..##akcja_pismo') is not null drop table ##akcja_pismo

    create table ##akcja_pismo (
    apis_id int
    ,app_guid varchar(max)
    ,app_nazwa_pliku varchar(max)
    )

    merge akcja_pismo as target using (
    select * from ##akcja_pismo_przychodzace) as source on 1=0
    when not matched then insert
    (apis_ak_id, apis_apisp_id, apis_data_stworzenia,[apis_us_id_tworzacy])
    values (ak_id,apisp_id,getdate(),5)
    output inserted.apis_id,source.app_guid,source.app_nazwa_pliku
    into ##akcja_pismo;

    alter table [dm_data_bps].[dbo].[akcja_pismo_plik] disable trigger [tr_akcja_pismo_plik_ins]

    insert into akcja_pismo_plik
    ([app_guid],[app_apis_id],[app_nazwa_pliku])
    select [app_guid],[apis_id],[app_nazwa_pliku] from ##akcja_pismo

    alter table [dm_data_bps].[dbo].[akcja_pismo_plik] enable trigger [tr_akcja_pismo_plik_ins]
end
```

Comment: If you try to answer this question, [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), odds are good that you'll also answer your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server compiles the procedure at creation and when it is first executed, verifying the entire procedure based on the context at that time.

For example, try the following query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P
AS
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T
SELECT 1 Y INTO #T
SELECT Y FROM #T

GO
CREATE TABLE #T (X INT)

GO
EXEC P
```

You will get an error ("Invalid column name 'Y'."), because when the procedure is compiled the table #T has only the column X.

To avoid this problem, you should make sure that the table #T either does not exist or has the right columns, before the procedure is executed.

One way would be to have another stored procedure (a wrapper):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P1
AS
SELECT 1 Y INTO #T
SELECT Y FROM #T

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE P2
AS
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T
EXEC P1

GO
CREATE TABLE #T (X INT)

GO
EXEC P2

GO
DROP PROCEDURE P1, P2
--DROP TABLE #T
```

Another way would be to use dynamic SQL, because that code is compiled separately, as if it would be another stored procedure.

A better way would be to make sure that temp tables are uniquely named in each stored procedure, unless sharing data between them is desired. For the later case, you can read http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#temptables for more insights.

Answer (score 0):

This error is also encountered when a stored procedure creates a **#temp** table and then fires a trigger which creates a **#temp** table with the same name. The SP **#temp** table is referenced by the trigger when the column names are explicit, (like `SELECT id FROM #temp;`), but the local trigger **#temp** table is referenced when `SELECT * FROM #temp;` is used.

Microsoft, if you are listening, could you kindly attend to it and retrofit existing supported versions with a maintenance update?

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking in your answer... Do you want temporary tables to be visible only in the procedure/trigger where they are created (not in any other nested procedures/triggers)? This will never happen, temporary tables are designed to allow sharing data between procedures. If you don't want to reuse temporary tables, give them unique names.